# passing geocoder information to the views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geocoding

I am using geocoder gem to get location information about the user. The issue I am facing is how to pass this information to the views and the application as a variable?

I do not want to query the api each time a new page is loaded but also want to retain the location information that views and controllers and use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass a gobal variable from a controller to a view you need to use `@` in front of your variables (e.g. `@geodata` being your object).

To save the information you should either add some field `location` to your `User` model or create a new `Geowhatever` model and assign it to each user (and maybe to other models via polymorphism).

This way you can do `@user.location` or `@user.geowhatever.location` in your views.

The only caveat when doing caching is to keep the cache up to date. Here an observer `UserObserver` can do the task.

Comment: user location can change from time to time, since I am doing geocoding via ip address so I can not save it in the user model. creating a new model and assigning it the value might be the way to go.

I will have to do some reading on this but thanks a alot for your help.